# Do I have to run apt-get remove package_name before apt-get purge package_name?

Tags: apt, uninstall, purge

I want to uninstall a package and erase its settings. **Do I have to run**:

- `sudo apt-get remove package_name`

and **only then**:

- `sudo apt-get purge package_name`

? Or **the latter would be enough?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Running the `remove` command will retain some of the configuration files in case you want to reinstall the package in the future.

If you want to completely remove a package and the configuration files, you can run the `purge` command alone. However, as pointed out by [@blueskies](https://askubuntu.com/users/1002823/blueskies), the `purge` command [will not delete any data or configuration stored in your home directory](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/apt.8.html).

Yes, the latter would be enough.

Comment: `sudo apt-get purge package-name` removes configuration files, EXCEPT for those in the /home folder.